# Devexpress menu missing after installation Visual Studio Community 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, devexpress, visual-studio-2017

I had Visual Studio 2012 and Devexpress 16.2.3. Now I installed VS Community 2017 RC, after that I "Repaired" installation of Devs, but menu and dev toolbox is still missing. I tried to deinstall and install again, restart computer, but still no luck. In VS2012 menu and toolbox is working.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to go through this DevExpress thread - [VS 2017 RC - Missing toolbox items and DevExpress menu item](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T467560). It has relevant information to your issue as below:

> You first re-install DevExpress v16.2 in Repair mode.
> It also may be necessary to perform additional steps as explained in
> the [How to resolve issues with Toolbox items](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/KA18574.aspx) article. If the
> problem persists, please provide the logs from the ToolboxAnalyzer
> tool and the DevExpress menu ([How to collect the “DevExpress” menu
> diagnostic logs](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/T219166.aspx)) for research.

Currently, support for Visual Studio 2017 RC is added to versions 16.1 and 16.2. Please review the [Using Visual Studio 2017 RC with DevExpress: some caution needed](https://www1.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T465248) blog post for more information.

Hope this help..